# Batch cant get value in if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, sqlite

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "count=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events;| sqlite3.exe system_events"
    echo %count% 
    set "sk=1000"
    if %count% gtr %sk% (
        echo Delete from Events where Id IN ( Select Id from Events limit 1^) ;| sqlite3.exe system_events" 
        pause
    )
    set "laik=%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%"
    echo INSERT INTO Events (Date, Time, Error_type) Values ("%Date%", "%laikas%", 0);| sqlite3.exe system_events
```

I have this problem, in %count% variable I get number of records of database, in echo it works fine it outputs number like 132, but in if statement I can see IF is comparing not 132 but

```
>if SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events;|sqlite3.exesystem_even
ts gtr 1000 (
```

And in that way IF statement is not working, wheres my problem? :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `if`, it is in the `set`. The way to retrieve the output from a command and assign it to a variable is to use a `for /f` command

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    cmd /q /c "echo select count(*) from Events;" ^|sqlite system_events
') do set "count=%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of SQLite capabilities. However there are workarounds. See [link.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/625472/Declare-loacl-variable-in-Sqlite-query)